# Sending data to Servlet thru AJAX POST Url, but if concurrent users try to send data servlet is not calling

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, jsp, servlets

Please help me on this.

I have some html table data on webpage. I am sending two columns data to servlet class through AJAX POST URL by clicking on "**Send**" button on webpage.

In servlet class I am getting data using request.getParameter("xyz"), and setting this value to session context, asI want to send this data to **webservice**.

It is working fine in my local system. But once I deploy on other server (INT or QA servers) and multiple users trying to send data by clicking on send button **servlet** is not calling at all. Why?

The data is coming fine on webpage and tested using alert conditions. But after that no **servlet** is calling, I tried with debug statements in **servlet**,but its not working. Please help.

I am not sure the below error related to this issue:
PWC4011: Unable to set request character encoding to UTF-8 from context , because request parameters have already been read, or ServletRequest.getReader() has already been called|#]

If yes, how can fix this to use this application by multiple users.

Comment: Here my AJAX code: $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "https://host:8080/InterfaceMonitoring/SendServlet",
                       
                        data: {
                            messagePayload: currPayload,
                            messageType: currType
                        }
                    });

Comment: Looks like you're sending the data to localhost (as noted by your comment)...

Comment: Luiggi Mendoza - I just have given example here. I am sending data on respected server where I deploy my code. Ex: If I deploy my code on INT server before deploying I change URL to that server and followed by my project name and servlet class. Please help.

Comment: Ex: If INT server I set URL is: http://<servername>:<portname>/InterfaceMonitoring/SendServlet

Comment: The problem seems that you're not sending the request at all. This can be probably by a firewall or any other agent blocking the request. To make sure you're sending the request to the right URL, you can use Chrome or Firefox with Firebug installed, press F12 and manage network traffic, then fire the expected request and see the results about it (and the related problems).

Comment: I am sending request by clicking on "send" button. See my complete script how I am sending. $(document).ready(function (){
 $('#resend').click(function() {
 $("input:checked").each(function () {
var currRow = $(this).closest("tr");
var currPayload = currRow.find('.msg-payload').text();
var currType = currRow.find('.msg-type').text();
alert("Payload Alert:"+ currPayload );
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://localhost:8080/InterfaceMonitoring/SendServlet",
    data: {
          messagePayload: currPayload,
          messageType: currType
                    }});}); });    })

Comment: I allready told you what you can do to spot the real problem...